# GA snippet for same family domain

Tags: google-analytics

I have to a GA account and have to add GA snippet for each site. There are 5 websites e.g. domain names are

```
mysite.uk
mysite.fi
mysite.no
mysite.se
mysite.fr
```

Agency suggested since all domains belong to the same mysite.* family they may use the same GA snippet, with different country code.

Is it possible to use one GA snippet in above scenarios ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/  or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one snippet. In this way the data ends up in only one Property and at that point you can create a View for each country.

Comment: Any link or article how to do it ?

Comment: There is no specific article, the work is trivial, the agency certainly knows. Just use only one code in each pages and create each View with a filter based on hostname.